# How to setup STUN server in a video chat app built using simple peer?

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, videochat, simple-peer

I was recently working on a project which requires video chatting. I used simple peer to setup a video call and use socket.io for signalling purposes. I then deployed my application. I realised when two peers on the same network join the call, the app works fine. But if two peers on different networks join the call, then I got an error stating process not defined and the call does not connects.
I read about this online and then figured out that I also have two configure a STUN and/or TURN server to extract ICE candidates and their public IP.

Can anyone please tell me how to setup a STUN server in my simple peer application? I have also read somewhere that google provides some free STUN servers to use but I dont know how to actually integrate them in my simple peer application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the RTCPeerConnection in your application, provide a configuration that includes `iceServers`.

This is [the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCIceServer/urls).

Example:

```
myPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: "stun:stunserver.example.org"
    }
  ]
});
```

You can find a list of free STUN servers [here](https://gist.github.com/zziuni/3741933).

You may also want to configure TURN servers to cover more complex NAT scenarios.

Comment: Also, can you suggest what are some ways in which I can configure a TUEN server? Are there any publically working TURN servers available?

Comment: A TURN service requires an investment in resources and maintenance, so in general there aren't free ones. However sometimes you can find some that are currently free, like this: https://www.metered.ca/tools/openrelay/ - In this section they show the structure to be used to configure your RTCPeerConnection: https://www.metered.ca/tools/openrelay/#-how-to-use